# What is the intuition of the rank of linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

I just want to make sure I understand the mechanics of finding the rank and range space of a linear map:

Problem from my text book:
Find the range space and rank of the map $$h: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathscr{P}_3$$ given by $$\begin{pmatrix}
    a\\
    b
  \end{pmatrix}  \mapsto  a+ax+ax^2$$

I understand that since $\{a(1+x+x^2)|a \in \mathbb{R} \}$
that it has a rank of 1 because it has a dimension of 1. I want to know so if I change the problem to

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    a\\
    b
  \end{pmatrix}  \mapsto  a+ax+bx^2$$

Thus $\{a(1+x)+bx^2|a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}$

Then the rank would be 2 (because there are now 2 free variables)?

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the correct idea, the rank tells you the dimension of the image of your map. In the examples you chose, it is especially easy to see what the rank should be, but in general this might be harder to read straight off of the map itself.

Comment: Thanks! What would you say are the steps for finding it for more nonobvious maps?

Comment: Are you familiar with the relationship between linear maps and matrices?

Comment: I don't think so. But I just googled the matrix of linear maps and a few articles came up. I will go read those.